# Why are we not able to lookup an objects value using dot property accessor if the key is dynamically generated?

Tags: javascript

**TLDR: You cannot use variables with dot notation.**

I mostly care about the theory of why we are not able to lookup an object's value based on a dynamically generated key (unless I am doing it wrong). If I **statically** type `game.team1` it looks up the value perfectly fine, however if the key is **dynamically** generated `game.key` it returns *undefined*. I know we can look it up using square bracket accessor `game[key]`, but why can't we do it using dot accessor? What gives? Shouldn't game.key in the first iteration of the loop evaluate to game.team1 and then look the key up in the object?

```
const game = {
  team1: 'Bayern Munich',
  team2: 'Borrussia Dortmund',
  players: [
    [
      'Neuer',
      'Pavard',
      'Martinez',
      'Alaba',
      'Davies',
      'Kimmich',
      'Goretzka',
      'Coman',
      'Muller',
      'Gnarby',
      'Lewandowski',
    ],
    [
      'Burki',
      'Schulz',
      'Hummels',
      'Akanji',
      'Hakimi',
      'Weigl',
      'Witsel',
      'Hazard',
      'Brandt',
      'Sancho',
      'Gotze',
    ],
  ],
  score: '4:0',
  scored: ['Lewandowski', 'Gnarby', 'Lewandowski', 'Hummels'],
  date: 'Nov 9th, 2037',
  odds: {
    team1: 1.33,
    x: 3.25,
    team2: 6.5,
  },
};

for (const [idx, scorer] of Object.entries(game.scored)) {
  console.log(`Goal #${Number(idx) + 1}: ${scorer}`);
}

for (const [key, odd] of Object.entries(game.odds)) {
  console.log(game.team1); // works ->  Bayern Munich,
  console.log(
    `${
      key === 'x' ? `Odd of draw: ${odd}` : `Odd of victory ${game.key}: ${odd}`
    }`
  ); // doesn't work -> Undefined
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the **dot notation** (`object.property`) properties can only be alphanumeric (and _ and $), can’t start with a number and cannot contain variables. That's why your `game.key` example doesn't work.

In **Bracket notation** (`object[property]`) property identifiers have to be a String and it is okay to use spaces, Strings that start with numbers and variables that reference a string. As in your example `key` is a variable that references a string, it works.

See: [*Property accessors*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)
and [*JavaScript Quickie— Dot Notation vs. Bracket Notation*](https://codeburst.io/javascript-quickie-dot-notation-vs-bracket-notation-333641c0f781)

Comment: Bracket notation will also accept a Symbol